# jQuery looping animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey all i am trying to get my code below to work in order for the "bug', when the mouse is moved over it, to animate like it's flying a little bit.

Here is my current code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

var navDuration = 150; //time in miliseconds
  var navJumpHeight = "0.45em";

  $('#bug1').hover(function() {
      $(this).animate({ top : "-="+navJumpHeight }, navDuration);            
  }, function() {
      $(this).animate({ top : "15px" }, navDuration);
  });

  });
  </script>
  <body>
  <a href="google.com"><img src="images/bug_05.png" width="90" height="73" id="bug1" /></a>
  </body>
```

The code above does not seem to move the image at all. I'm trying to make an effect that loops like the bug is flying (hovering) a little when the user places their mouse over it.

Any help would be great! :o)

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `top` style to have any effect you need to position the element, in this case `position: relative`, like this:

```
​#bug1 { position: relative; }​
```

[You can see it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/D8fpa/).  You may want `0px` instead of `15px` in your `mouseleave` animation as well, so it resets to it's original position, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/D8fpa/1/).

Comment: Awesome, Nick. How would i achieve the looping animation so that it looks like its still flying (hovering) until the user goes off of it?

Comment: @StealthRT - Something like this would work: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6ERaj/

Comment: SWEET! Thanks so much for you're help there, Nick! :o)

Answer (score 0):

"Top" can only work with position relative/absolute.

```
<img src="images/bug_05.png" width="90" height="73" id="bug1" 
   style="position:relative"/>
```

**EDIT :** 
As pointed by Nick Craver, absolute will be used rarely, most of the time in image is somewhere in a div and you want relative position to that div, no absolute position in the page.

Comment: You would rarely if ever want `position: absolute;` here, when in a hover situation and the script he has you want `relative`.

Comment: Indeed, it will probably be in a div somewhere. Edited.